# How to Enable / Disable div based on directives Angular 4 / 5?

Tags: angular, typescript, angular5, angular-directive

I was trying to do structural kind of directive. I have list of checkbox and when checkbox checked, i need to enable div and if checkbox unchecked, i need to disable div.

So i tried below code and it successfully enable, disable div, but issue is i need to show this div end page but this directive create/destroy div next to checkbox.

I belive ViewContainerRef is taking checkbox place as reference and it create div next to checkbox. How to give viewcontainerref dynamically for each div

```
import { Directive, TemplateRef, ViewContainerRef, Input, HostListener, HostBinding } from '@angular/core';

@Directive({
    selector: '[showIfAdditional]'
})

export class ShowIfAdditionalDirective {
    private component: any;
    private tRef: TemplateRef<any>;
    private opened: boolean;
    constructor(public vcRef: ViewContainerRef) { }

    @Input() set showIfAdditional(value: any) {
        if (value !== this.component) {
            this.component = value;
        }
    }

    @Input('showIfAdditionalContent') set template(value: TemplateRef<any>) {
        if (value !== this.tRef) {
            this.tRef = value;
        }
    }

    @HostListener('click') public onClick(): void {
        this.toggle();
    }

    public toggle(): void {
        if (this.opened) {
            this.vcRef.clear();
        } else {
            this.vcRef.createEmbeddedView(this.tRef, { $implicit: this.component });                this.render();
        }
        this.opened = this.vcRef.length > 0;
    }
}
```

HTML code

```
<div #checkBoxDiv>
    <mat-checkbox *ngFor="let list1 of componentsList1 [showIfAdditional]="list1.value" [showIfAdditionalContent]="expandRowDiv">
      {{list1.value}}
    </mat-checkbox>
<div>
     <ng-template #expandRowDiv let-component>
          <div style="overflow: hidden">
              <h1>{{component|json}}</h1>
          </div>
    </ng-template>
```

So this above code create destroy div next to checkbox like below

```
<div #checkBoxDiv>
[*] CHK1
dynamically_creatediv_comes_here
[] CHK2
[] CHK3
...
</div>
```

But i need to create this div outside of this #checkboxDiv, something like this

```
<div #checkBoxDiv>
[*] CHK1
[] CHK2
[] CHK3
...
</div>

create_dynamically_div_here
```

Please someone help on it

Comment: What's wrong with *ngIf? Why reinvent that wheel? Bind your checkbox to a boolean value (using ngModel), and use *ngIf to display or remove the associated div based on the value of the boolean.

Comment: The directive is supposed to control the element where it belongs to and its children. showIfAdditional and expandRowDiv should have a common parent directive/component that will sort this out.

Comment: Right now we using NgIf only but project requested us to do in this type :-/